# Maintain SubSubFolder structure While Merging into Another Folder [Duplicate FolderNames Will Exist]

Tags: powershell, batch-file, merge, directory

I currently receive emails for tickets and responses. They are automatically sent to folders as pdf. I create cover pages for them. So essential 3 sections that will eventually become one big pdf (cover, ticket, & response). 
Ticket numbers are 14 digits and usually the emails contain that ticket number somewhere in the subject line (which is the pdf title). So I use BulkRenameUtility and Regex to rename every ticket to the 14 digit ticket number, with "-Ticket" after it. All responses then get named to the 14 digit ticket number, prefixed with a 2 (so that pdftk combines it last), and if there is multiple responses sequentially numbered. All covers are automatically generated with "10A-" then the 14 digit ticket number, then the job number. Ticket numbers are in the format YYMMDDHHNN####. So that makes pdftk compile these as Cover, ticket, then response.
But before pdftk can combine the pdfs into one. I need them to be in the same folder. I use a batch script to sort all covers into a folder with the 14 digit ticket name as the foldername, the same for the responses and tickets. So i end up with (depending on the number of tickets, right now I have 96) many subfolders like this.

```
.....OpenLocates
..........Current
...............Complete
....................[EMPTY]
...............Covers #There will be one cover per job.
....................18051400000001
.........................10A-18051400000001_218001.pdf
....................18051400000002
.........................10A-18051400000002_217022.pdf
...............Responses #There will be multiple responses per ticket.
....................18051400000001
.........................218051400000001.pdf
.........................218051400000001_1.pdf
.........................218051400000001_2.pdf
....................18051400000002
.........................218051400000002.pdf
.........................218051400000002_1.pdf
.........................218051400000002_2.pdf
...............Tickets #There *can* be multiple tickets per job.
....................18051400000001
.........................18051400000001-Ticket.pdf
....................18051400000002
.........................18051400000002-Ticket.pdf
```

What I need is for all those subfolders to merge into one. There should not ever be a duplicate filename since BRU does sequentially number duplicates when renaming the pdf files in the first place.

```
.....OpenLocates
..........Current
...............Complete
....................18051400000001
.........................10A-18051400000001_218001.pdf
.........................18051400000001-Ticket.pdf
.........................218051400000001.pdf
.........................218051400000001_1.pdf
.........................218051400000001_2.pdf
....................18051400000002
.........................10A-18051400000002_217022.pdf
.........................18051400000002-Ticket.pdf
.........................218051400000002.pdf
.........................218051400000002_1.pdf
.........................218051400000002_2.pdf
```

The batch script is this:

```
@echo on

::CALLALL
Call :SortCovers
Call :SortResponses
Call :SortTickets
goto :EOF

:SortCovers
cd L:\OpenLocates\Current\Covers

for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d /b') do (
    if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :SortCoversFunction "%%~a"
    )

goto :EOF

:SortCoversFunction
set file=%~1
set dir=%file:~4,14%
md "%dir%" 2>nul
move "%file%" "%dir%"
goto :EOF

:SortResponses
cd L:\OpenLocates\Current\Responses

for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d /b') do (
    if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :SortResponsesFunction "%%~a"
    )

goto :EOF


:SortResponsesFunction
set file=%~1
set dir=%file:~1,14%
md "%dir%" 2>nul
move "%file%" "%dir%"
goto :EOF


:SortTickets
cd L:\OpenLocates\Current\Tickets

for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d /b') do (
    if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :SortTicketsFunction "%%~a"
    )

goto :EOF

:SortTicketsFunction
set file=%~1
set dir=%file:~0,14%
md "%dir%" 2>nul
move "%file%" "%dir%"
goto :EOF
```

Right now i'm cut/pasting the folders and clicking OK on the merge popup in windows explorer.
But i have to teach my whole process to another person next week, and i'd like to simplify it down. 
After I have all my folders merged I run a powershell script with PDFTK to combine the pdf files and save them in the parent folder.

I could really use some help on getting the subfolders of Covers, Responses and Tickets to move out to the Complete folder merging the duplicate foldernames to create one folder with all my files for each ticket number so I can run the following powershell script that does successfully combine them in the correct order.

```
$pdftk = "C:\SymLinks\Combine\pdftk.exe"
$inputFolder = "L:\OpenLocates\Current\Complete"
gci $inputfolder -r -include *.pdf | sort-object | group DirectoryName | % {& $PDFtk $_.group CAT OUTPUT "$($_.Name | Split-Path -Parent)\$($_.Name | Split-Path -Leaf).pdf" verbose}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried several different batch and powershell scripts and none seem to be working for me.

Edit: I do combine all the ticket numbers for one job into one folder before combining the PDFs. All the folders get renamed to the job name also before combining that final PDF.

Comment: `%~dpnx0` in a sub represents the name of the sub, not the name of the batch. There are other errors in a too broad question. Limit this to single questions in a [mcve].

Comment: The batch script works fine. I was just trying to show the process i was currently using. What I need is to "Merge" folders of the same name from three sub folders to one parent folder. Every time I try, it overwrites the folder and I end up with only "Responses" or only "Tickets". Is there a powershell or batch cmd that tells Windows Explorer to Merge folders if they already exist and not overwrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stay with the more modern script langugage.
I created a test environment on my ramdisk A:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\05\19\SO_50419164.ps1

$Sources = ("A:\OpenLocates\Current\Covers\",
            "A:\OpenLocates\Current\Responses\",
            "A:\OpenLocates\Current\Tickets\")

$Target =   "A:\OpenLocates\Current\Complete\"

ForEach ($Source in $Sources){
    Get-ChildItem $Source -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        $TargetSub = Join-Path $Target $_.Name
        If (!(Test-Path $TargetSub)){ MD $TargetSub |Out-Null}
        Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File | Move -Dest $TargetSub
        Remove-Item $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Tree a: /F before

```
A:\
└───OpenLocates
    └───Current
        ├───Complete
        ├───Covers
        │   ├───18051400000001
        │   │       10A-18051400000001_218001.pdf
        │   │
        │   └───18051400000002
        │           10A-18051400000002_217022.pdf
        │
        ├───Responses
        │   ├───18051400000001
        │   │       218051400000001.pdf
        │   │       218051400000001_1.pdf
        │   │       218051400000001_2.pdf
        │   │
        │   └───18051400000002
        │           218051400000002.pdf
        │           218051400000002_1.pdf
        │           218051400000002_2.pdf
        │
        └───Tickets
            ├───18051400000001
            │       18051400000001-Ticket.pdf
            │
            └───18051400000002
                    18051400000002-Ticket.pdf
```

And after running the script:

```
A:\
└───OpenLocates
    └───Current
        ├───Complete
        │   ├───18051400000001
        │   │       10A-18051400000001_218001.pdf
        │   │       18051400000001-Ticket.pdf
        │   │       218051400000001.pdf
        │   │       218051400000001_1.pdf
        │   │       218051400000001_2.pdf
        │   │
        │   └───18051400000002
        │           10A-18051400000002_217022.pdf
        │           18051400000002-Ticket.pdf
        │           218051400000002.pdf
        │           218051400000002_1.pdf
        │           218051400000002_2.pdf
        │
        ├───Covers
        ├───Responses
        └───Tickets
```